# sql column where specific value is searched for the customer

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a database with customer numbers and some other columns.
Now I've got this sql ready but it still misses a thing and I can't figure out how to get it right. What I need is to get all the customers with soort = 041 and they may also have soort 040 but they cannot have soort = 043.

```
select  *
from tabel1 join tabel2 on 1_key_nummer = 2_key_nummer
where typen = 'regulier'
and datum_vanaf   < sysdate
and nvl(datum_tot, '31-12-9999') > sysdate
and einde_registratie is null
and soort = 041
```

It tried doing "soort not in 043" but it still gives me customers back that also have 043.

Comment: and soort <> 043 not working?

Comment: Your query is much more complicated than your question.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select customer_number
from tabel1 join
     tabel2
     on 1_key_nummer = 2_key_nummer
where typen = 'regulier' and
      datum_vanaf   < sysdate
      (datum_tot is null or datum_tot > sysdate) and
      einde_registratie is null
gropu by customer_number
having sum(case when soort in (040, 041) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when soort = 043 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Note that the `0` before the numeric value is suspicious.  It doesn't mean anything.  If this is a string, then use single quotes (`'041'`).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
select  *
from tabel1 join tabel2 on 1_key_nummer = 2_key_nummer
where typen = 'regulier'
and datum_vanaf   < sysdate
and nvl(datum_tot, '31-12-9999') > sysdate
and einde_registratie is null
and ((soort = 041 OR soort = 040) and soort <> 043)
```

I' m a little bit confused about the data-type of the column soort. Is it an INTEGER od CHAR/VARCHAR, so try instead:

```
and ((soort = '041' OR soort = '040') and soort <> '043')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with only one set of parenthesis

```
select  *
from tabel1 join tabel2 on 1_key_nummer = 2_key_nummer
where typen = 'regulier'
and datum_vanaf   < sysdate
and nvl(datum_tot, '31-12-9999') > sysdate
and einde_registratie is null
and (soort = 041 OR soort = 040) -- Here we are saying soort can be either 40 or 41
and soort <> 043--Here we are saying soort cannot be 43
```